# Remapping one theme accent to another in a new template

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

We have an old corporate PowerPoint template that we would like to innovate. The old template includes colors (the theme terminology calls these "Accents") that we are changing as well.

The old template has been in use for over a decade and there are countless slides built using it. When I would simply paste old slides into the new template, the color accents would be assigned based on their order; this means that what was Accent #1 (which was red) in the old would now be Accent #1 (blue in the new). This way, most graphics would need hand tuning to make them usable again. And given the number of slides we have, this would be an endless job.

I would like to find out if it is possible to somehow map or auto reassign colors/accents when pasting old slides into the new presentation. Something like "When pasting an object with Accent #1 from the old themed presentation, use Accent #4 instead". Is there any way to do this?

[image: Scheme]